# OpenShift serving / hosting is not working for node js app with react static files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, openshift, devops

I am trying to host a node js app on OpenShift  container platform using web console.
my app is simple node js app which serving static React storybook build files. 
I am able to get my app working in local host,But serving/hosting is not working in open shift. I can not see any build/ deployment error also in OpenShift log. Also POD has been created successfully.

From the log, I can see React’s Storybook build is success and build folder is created. Also it is pushing image to docker registry and push successful. 
After the deployment if I open the url it is blank for sometime then showing ‘site can’t be reached’

This is the folder structure:

```
package.json
index.js
client
  build
  node_modules
  src
  package.json
```

The parent package.json contains below scrips

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm run buildClient", /* build client will start storybook build and create build folder*/
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

This is my index.js

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
module.exports = app;
```

I am expecting once pod has been created, hosting url should open the storybook. But if I open the url it is blank for sometime then showing ‘site can’t be reached’

Comment: The "Site can't be reached" sounds like a DNS lookup error. Make sure to configure DNS records for a custom [route](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html) host or that the [wildcard DNS entry](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/prerequisites.html#wildcard-dns-prereq) is configured properly for that OpenShift Container Platform cluster. You can try adding output of `dig <hosting_url>` (or something similar) to your question.

Comment: @Tutu can u please share the solution I'm facing the same issue